# jQuery - Call function if a certain variable is more than 1

Tags: jquery

I’m a total rookie at jQuery but with some help I managed to create a script to switch images which also keeps track of how many images are available and when the last or first image is active so it will deactivate the respective button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var imageNumber = 1;

    var $images = $(".npc-image");

    var changeImage = function(newImage) {

        if (newImage < 1 || newImage > $images.length) return;

        if (imageNumber != newImage) {
            $images.eq(imageNumber-1).hide();
            $images.eq(newImage-1).show();
            imageNumber = newImage;
        }

        $("#arrow-previous button").toggleClass("active", imageNumber > 1);
        $("#arrow-next button").toggleClass("active", imageNumber < $images.length);

    };

    $("#arrow-previous button").click(function() { changeImage(imageNumber-1); });
    $("#arrow-next button").click(function() { changeImage(imageNumber+1); });

    changeImage(1);

    $("#npc-image-container").hover(function() {

        $("#images-navigation").fadeToggle(400, function() {

        });

    });

});
```

This is how it looks online:
http://www.tamriel-hero.de/typo3_grau_01/fileadmin/templates/_new/vorlage.html

I want that last hover function only to run if $images is more than one. I tried some stuff but unfortunately it didn’t work out. I’m sure it’s quite simple but since I really don’t have much of a clue about jQuerys syntax I wanted to ask you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#npc-image-container").hover(function() {
    if($images.length > 0) {
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!